# How to listen to events in real time with Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, socket.io, rxjs

Im trying to listen in realtime for socket.io events, i have a backend in Node, emiting it, and a front end Service listening to it, but it only shows in the view after i reload the page.

My application will send a lot of events in seconds (each event is a Post request), after i send a post request, my back-end console.log is instant (which is what i want), but as i said, my front-end isn't.

Node:

```
const event = req.body;

app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('event', require('util').inspect(event));
  });

  res.json({
    status: 'ok'
  });
});
```

Service:

```
observable:Observable<string>;
  socket;

  constructor() {
    this.socket = io("http://localhost:8080");
  }

  getData(event: String) : Subject<any> {
    let subj = new Subject;
    this.socket.on(event, data => subj.next(data)); 

    return subj;
  }
```

Component:

```
constructor(private _eventsService : EventsService) {
    this._eventsService.getData('event').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data); // Only logs after reload
    });
  }
```

Basically i want to keep listening to events in the Front-end, and when i send a Post request to /webhook, will emit that event, and my view updates (or logs, etc).

Comment: You may find this article interesting https://medium.freecodecamp.org/reactive-thinking-how-to-design-a-distributed-system-with-rxjs-websockets-and-node-57d772f89260

Answer (score 0):

I think event is defined in wrong scope and io.sockets.on('connection' should not get called every time there is a post.

If you are trying to broadcast to all connected clients each time their is a post
then i would get rid of the io.sockets.on('connection'
and just use:

```
const inspect = require('util').inspect;
app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {
  io.emit('event', inspect(req.body));

  res.json({
    status: 'ok'
  });
});
```

If you only want to emit and event back to the client that posted it, then you would need to include the socket.id in the payload and use that to send a message back to the client.
Assuming req.body is an object, something like:

```
const inspect = require('util').inspect;
app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.socketId){
    io.to(req.body.socketId).emit('event', inspect(req.body));
  }
  res.json({
    status: 'ok'
  });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I think event is defined in wrong scope"? And you are right about the connection inside the post, but for some reason, when i remove it, it says io.emit() is not a function, maybe is my import? Im importing socket.io in the app.js. where my express server is, and then, in the app, im doing module.exports = io, and requiring in the routes file before the post

Comment: const event = req.body; // <-- where does this req come from? shouldn't req be from the webhook handler?

app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {

Comment: const SocketIO = require('socket.io'); const io = socketIO(server, {}); // <- this io is the one required by my example. also my example is Socket.io v2.x